# Reference obj-c object in c++ code

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

*Disclaimer* I'm a PHP programmer with experience in Java, and have dabbled with Obj-C/C++/C.

I'm trying to use the [IB SDK](http://interactivebrokers.github.io/#) inside an Obj-C application. I've got the hang of the compilation with .mm vs. .cpp vs .m files.

The IB API has a Send and Recieve pattern where a class `EClientSocketBase` sends data to the API and a second class `EWrapper` receives data from from the API in a separate thread.

I have an obj-c wrapper around a class, `CppSend`, inherited from `EClientSocketBase` class, `ObjCSend` to send data to the api. Call c++ classes from obj-c doesn't seem to be a problem. But, I run into a problem when I try to do the reverse. I don't know how to either inject a class, say `ObjCRecieve`, to handle call backs in `EWrapper`.

My objc sender, looks like this:

```cpp
// This class sends messages to CppSend
@interface ObjCSend
@property (atomic) CppSend* client;
...
@end
```

and my cpp sender looks like this:

```cpp
#import "CppReceive.h"
// This class sends messages to the IB Api.
class CppSend: public EClientSocketBase {
    public:
        CppReceive * incomingFromAPI;
        ...
}
```

and my cpp receiver looks like this:

```cpp
#import "ObjCReceive.h"
// This class receives messages from the IB API, containing
// data relevant to the messages sent in CppSend
class CppReceive: public EWrapper {
    public:
        ObjCRecieve *outgoingToGUI;
        void setObjCReceive(ObjReceive * delegate);
        ...
}
```

Here's what I've got for my Obj-C receiver:

```cpp
// This class should receive messages from CppReceive, containing
// data relevant to the messages sent in CppSend
@interface ObjCReceive
- (void)callbackHandler;
@end
```

My problem is in `CppReceive->delegate`. I get a compilation error, `"Unknown type name 'ObjCReceive'"`. I assume this is because the c++ header can't appropriately reference the obj-c interface as a type.

How would I create an Obj-C class, which can have an appropriate type to be parsed and compiled in a C++ class?

Edit: The data flow would be something like this

```
------------
| ObjCSend |
------------
     |
     V
-----------
| CppSend |
-----------
     |
     V
  --------
 ( IB API )
  --------
     |
     V
--------------
| CppReceive |
--------------
     |
     V
--------------
| ObjReceive |
--------------
```

Comment: You need to convert both files to ObjC++, or use some middle-man.  C++ will actually pollute your Objective-C files.

Comment: What do you mean by convert them or use some middle man? All the header files are ".h" and all the sources files are ".mm". I'm trying to create a middle man with the ObjCSend/Receive classes.

Comment: Then the ObjC++ file you're trying to access that member in has no idea what the interface for that type looks like.  Check your imports, you should be able to reference Objective-C types just fine.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. Should a normal Obj-C interface be recognised by C++ as a normal type?

Comment: By C++, no.  By Objective-C++, yes.  In a purely C++ context, Objective-C interfaces are meaningless.

Comment: Ok, so inside `CppReceive`, how can I send messages (either directly, or indirectly) to `ObjCReceive`?

Comment: By treating it like any other Objective-C object (`[reciever message:argument]`).  It would be helpful to have a little more context.  How about the line of code specifically causing you trouble and the code around it along with the name and extension of the file it's contained in.

Comment: Are your C++ classes in files with extension `.mm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an Objective-C object or constructs inside a C/C++ program.

To be able to use Objective-C object, you may use pimpl-idiom (Pointer to implementation).

For example, in your case, there will be a class `CppSendImpl` and `CppSend` will have its pointer.

This `CppSendImpl` can be implemented in Objective-C++ (not Objective-C) where it implements the code requiring Objective-C and can interface with Objective-C object which you want.

Here, you can use Objective-C construct. But if your `CppSend` is meant for C++ client also, you cannot expose or use any of the Objective-C construct outside implementation class.